# Filtering UDS from output of netstat without grep

Tags: linux, netstat

how I cat to filter out information about Unix Domain Sockets from netstat output without grep?
Is there some option for command (I not found it in man of netstat).

Thank you for ahead.

Comment: Why not use grep?

Comment: Because it remains header of the section (few lines above "unix" record set) and it is too long every time to write it, and it is neccessary to do alias for this on each server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
netstat -tulpn
```

-t tcp
-u udp
-l listenning
-p program name
-n use addresses rather then DNS names

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
netstat -46
```

Comment: This is not solution. In netstat --inet (also with -a swithch) I don't get the following line: "tcp        0      0 ::ffff:192.168.2.200:ssh    ::ffff:192.168.2.100:44799  ESTABLISHED". But I get it without --inet

Comment: Sorry, forgot about IPv6. Should work now

Comment: No, acording to man, netstat do not get this parameters... May be we told about different releases. I speak about: net-tools 1.60 netstat 1.42 (2001-04-15) for Linux. So I think that there is no such option. The only way is to use grep command. It is possible to put alias for this in /etc/bashrc. I put this answer with all this comments like accepted. Thank you any way.

Comment: Strange. You can also try `-A inet,inet6`, or `--inet --inet6`. All of these options, including `-46`, are fully equivalent and work for me on netstat 1.42. Hope you'll fix anything that.

Comment: Yes, it is works :)